# Laravel AWS Download

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, laravel-5

I started a new project via Laravel 5.1 and came to the part where I need to download a file with s3 (AWS). I noticed that keeps files in xml format.

How do I download a file to s3? Here's what I have so far:

Controller

```
//$key = urldecode($key);


//This way found file as .xml but can't get zip file?!
$key = str_replace('.zip', '.xml', $firmware->key);
$test = Storage::disk('s3')->get('db/'.$key);

//dd($test);  this get: 
FileNotFoundException in FilesystemAdapter.php line 58:
db/Toshiba\07GAH\TOSHIBA MK8007GAH-BG002H0-Y6HNW0EOW.xml*

$data = (array) simplexml_load_string($test) or die("Can't read XML for $manifest");
//dd($data);
//dd($test);

return  response()->download('db/'.$data['key']);
```

This is error I see in the browser when in db change "\" in "/"

[image: screenshot]

Comment: you took a photo of your monitor?!?!?

Comment: Really?! When you sharing photo with your contacts it is twice easier to take a picture and not take ss. You can see the error i will not provide ss..

Comment: This is how i do in Laravel 5.1
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36778167/download-from-laravel-storage-without-loading-whole-file-in-memory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36778167/download-from-laravel-storage-without-loading-whole-file-in-memory)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is self explained. You get that exception `FileNotFoundException` because .. well file was not found on the server with provided name.

You should first check if file exists on the server and handle it that way [Laravel documentation for File System](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/filesystem#retrieving-files). If you go a bit further down on that documentation you have section on how to [list all files from directory](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/filesystem#directories) tho in your case it would be something like

```
$files = Storage::disk('s3')->files(); //or allFiles() return sub dir files also
dd($files);
```

this is for debuging and to see what you're doing wrong. With data that you get from it, you can fix your errors and continue with building your app.