# Laravel: pass var to controller to retrieve item from storage dynamically

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have the following function in my `FileController` that retrieves a video from my `storage (local)`:

```
function getVideo() {

    $video = Storage::disk('local')->get("uploads/map_name/name_of_video.mp4");
    $response = Response::make( $video, 200 );
    $response->header( 'Content-Type', 'video/mp4' );

    return $response;
}
```

In my `web.php` i have the following `route`:

```
Route::get('/get-video/', 'FileController@getVideo')->name('get-video');
```

Last, in my `view`, i have the following:

```
<video controls>

    <source src="{{ route('get-video') }}" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.

</video>
```

This works fine. The video is shown in my view. However, i would like to make this function dynamic but i can't seem to get this working. I have made the following changes:

First, i passed a `var` to the `getVideo` function and pass it to the `get` function:

```
function getVideo($video_name) {

    $video = Storage::disk('local')->get("uploads/{$video_name}");
    $response = Response::make( $video, 200 );
    $response->header( 'Content-Type', 'video/mp4' );

    return $response;
}
```

Then, i changed the `route` to take a `var`:

```
Route::get('/get-video/{video_name}', 'FileController@getVideo')->name('get-video');
```

And finally, in my `view`, i pass the `var` to the `route`

```
<video controls>

    <source src="{{ route('get-video', ['video_name' => '/map_name/name_of_video.mp4']) }}" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.

</video>
```

This, however, results in a 404 not found. I get this route:
`https://mysite.local/get-video/map_name/name_of_video.mp4`.

Notice that the `/upload` part doesn't get rendered. However, if i add this manually, the route fails as well.

I already did the `php artisan storage:link` as well.

Sidenote: the `/map_name/name_of_video.mp4` part is something I can retrieve from the `database` for each video.

Comment: A little more off-topic but a few remarks I did want to leave for future research / improvements to your code:
- Make sure users cannot access video's (or possibly other files stored) they shouldn't by checking the filename against a record in your database for example.
- Research about streaming the file back to the user instead of using `get` and making it into a response since that will load the whole file in memory which can cause issues with large files. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29747052/1580028

Comment: I will look into this! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has to do with you using a `/` character in the route parameter which by default does not work because that is a separator symbol used to separate route parameters.

You can try and define the route like the following to overcome that:

```
Route::get('/get-video/{video_name}', 'FileController@getVideo')->name('get-video')->where('video_name', '(.*)');
```

The in the `where` you can define a regex that matches the route parameter, in this case `.*` matches everything that comes after `/get-video/`.

You can than use it like:

```
{{ route('get-video', ['video_name' => 'map_name/name_of_video.mp4']) }}
```

Not I removed the leading `/` in the route example to prevent a duplicated `/` character in the path.